# What did the helpless captives from the start of the game do?

Tags: bioshock-infinite

At the start of the game

> Booker is asked to throw a ball at a tied up couple of a black woman and a white man. However, it's never explained why they are being balled (as in stoned, only with balls). It seems to me, from the set, that they have had interracial relations, but it's never said (at least not to me) that interracial relations are forbidden and not just frowned upon.

Also,

> are they supposed to die from the balling as in a real stoning, or just be humiliated?

Comment: I'm not through the game, but in the area where there are separate bathrooms for the Irish and colored people sort of implies that interracial relations are frowned upon doesn't it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's explicitly because they're an interracial couple.

Remember, the game is set in the early 20th century -  such relationships weren't just frowned upon, they were often explicitly illegal. And even when they *weren't* explicitly illegal, they were generally *implicitly* illegal, in the sense that people engaged in them would often end up murdered.

Answer (score -1):

You can find few propaganda posters about keeping "*race clean*" in game.

As @LessPop_MoreFizz writed Ssch interracial couple was not agreed by law in the time of Bioshock Infinite action.